# Unisex word for 3rd person?

Tags: personal-pronouns

What can you call a 3rd person who's gender is unknown?

> He - Male
>
> She - Female

I've never heard of an unisex word for 3rd person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word that has been used in English for centuries is *they*.

Comment: Yup - when I hear someone do this, that's what they say...

Comment: Didn't thought of that... Is there any other word?

Comment: Not really. Why would you want another one?

Comment: 'They' can be mixed for plural, so I thought if there'd be any other word.

Comment: _You_ is used for singular and plural as well, and doesn't seem to cause any problems.